# How to apply config for my scully plugin?

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a plugin on scully,static site generator on angular.
But I cannot spplya my config object for my plugin.

I could:

- Install markdown support and generate some posts from markdown by scully..
- Making a plugin that make routes some routes.
- Register the plugin as "route process" by registerPlugin func.
- Run and successfuly generate routes depending on my config object...on the plugin script file.

Problem:

- Now , The config object is defined in the same .ts script file with plugin code.
- I want to inject my config object on another script file , such as scully.**.config.ts. I want to make my plugin easier to re-use.
- But I cannot overwrite config by setConfig function.

The plugin code :

```
import { HandledRoute, registerPlugin, RouteTypes } from "@scullyio/scully"

export const ARCHIVES_PLUGIN = 'archive'

export interface ArchivePluginConfig {
    root:string;
    articleRoute: string;
    archivePrefixRoute: string;
    archiveSize:number;
}

export const EXAMPLE_CONFIGS: ArchivePluginConfig[] =[{
    root:"/blog",
    articleRoute: "/blog/articles",
    archivePrefixRoute: "/archives",
    archiveSize:8,
}];

export function archivePlugin(routes: HandledRoute[], config?:ArchivePluginConfig[]): Promise<HandledRoute[]> {
    config = (config ==undefined || config.length<1)? EXAMPLE_CONFIGS:config;

    config.forEach(config => {       
        //add archives for blog
        let posts = routes.filter((route) => route.route.startsWith(config.articleRoute));
        let archiveCount=Math.floor(posts.length/config.archiveSize)+1;
        
        let archives:HandledRoute[]=[];
        for (let page = 1; page <= archiveCount; page++) {
            archives.push({route:`${config.root}${config.archivePrefixRoute}/${page}`}) 
        }
        archives.forEach(element => {
            routes.push(element);
        });
    });
    return Promise.resolve(routes);
}

registerPlugin("routeProcess", ARCHIVES_PLUGIN, archivePlugin, [])
```

scully.{myproject}.config.ts code:

```
import { ScullyConfig, setPluginConfig } from '@scullyio/scully';
import './scully/plugins/archive';
import { ArchivePluginConfig, ARCHIVES_PLUGIN  ,archivePlugin} from './scully/plugins/archive';

setPluginConfig('md', { enableSyntaxHighlighting: true });

const archiveConfig:ArchivePluginConfig[]=[
  {
    root:"/blog",
    articleRoute:"blog/article",
    archiveSize:8,
    archivePrefixRoute:"/articles",
  }
]
setPluginConfig<ArchivePluginConfig[]>(ARCHIVES_PLUGIN,'routeProcess',archiveConfig);

const defaultPostRenderers = ['seoHrefOptimise'];

export const config: ScullyConfig = {
  defaultPostRenderers,
  projectRoot: "./",
  projectName: "jl-dotnet",
  outDir: './dist/static',
  routes: {
    '/blog/article/:post': {
      type: 'contentFolder',
      post: {
        folder: "./article/blog"
      }
    },
  }
};
```

Result:
There generated some routes not depending on config defined at scully.**.config.ts but defined at plugin;
the generated routes located on "/archives" not on "/articles"

Enviroment?:

- OS:windows 10
- editor:vscode
- console:git-bash
- nodejs:v14.16.1
- npm:7.12.0
- I created new project by ngcli
- I installed scully via npm on gitbash.

I attempt to make my blog by angular and scully as static site.
And I made a plugin for generate archives , consist of multiple pages.
I made a similar plugin , that generate category archive.
But same problem occurs.

This line works,inject config for markdown plugin,

```
setPluginConfig('md', { enableSyntaxHighlighting: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.

- remove "config" arguments from plugin function
- call getConfig function and cache result into variable
- config needs not to be array. So I need to define wrapping interface. And I use the interface alternatively.